# DataGrid does not show rows that have null Foreign Key value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SalesInvoiceID}" Header="Sales Invoice ID" Width="100"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CustomerID}" Header="Customer ID" Width="100"/>                  
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

`CustomerID` is a foreign key which can be `null` in database. `DataGrid` Does not show those rows who's `CustomerID`is null. Please help.

I want to show all rows including those rows also who's `CustomerID` field( which is foreign key) is null . i used the following query in `c#`

```
select s.SalesInvoiceID,c.CustomerID from SalesInvoiceID s inner join Customer c on s.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
```

I want

```
SalesInvoiceID  CustomerID
---------------------------
1               23
2               Null
3               24
4               Null
```

Comment: what exactly do you want it to show if it is null? You can use a Converter if you want something to show

Comment: And what you are doing is creating columns, not rows. So I am unsure what you are doing.

Comment: "SELECT s.SalesInvoiceID,c.CustomerID from SalesInvoiceID s inner join Customer c on s.CustomerID=c.CustomerID"

Comment: Please edit the original question if you want to add more information instead of posting them in comments.

Comment: i want to show all rows even if CustomerID coloumn value is null

Comment: `LEFT JOIN`, not `INNER`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not displaying those rows because you are not giving it those rows

Test your query in SSMS

```
SELECT s.SalesInvoiceID, c.CustomerID 
from SalesInvoiceID s 
inner join Customer c 
   on s.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

Try

```
left join Customer c
```